# GCP cloud spanner, is it serverless?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I could find out the GCP Cloud SQL is not serverless. But I could not find about the same with GCP Cloud Spanner.

Is GCP cloud spanner serverless?

Comment: WHat's your definition of serverless? What are the key points? Many have different definitions, that's why it's difficult to answer you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCP Cloud Spanner uses managed instances in the same way GCP Cloud SQL does, so they are not serverless.

Comment: from what i remember, when creating spanner db i don't see it asking to choose instances type. Is that how it is or am i missing something. I don't have access to cluster right now to verify. +1

Comment: That's right, a virtual server is created to host the database(s) but there is no access to it.

Answer (score 0):

The GCP cloud spanner runs on a virtual server. Even though you don't get to configure the virtual server, it runs in the background. Therefore, cloud spanner is NOT serverless.

GCP Serverless Database and storages: Memorystore, Cloud Datastore, Firestore, Cloud storage, Firebase

GCP Non-serverless Database and storages: Cloud SQL, Cloud Spanner, Cloud Bigtable, BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. GCP spanner is not serverless.
It depends on your use case whether you want to use cloud sql or spanner.
Spanner is used for high volume of data which needs to be stored example : Oracle database data can be stored in spanner.
Cloud sql is recommended for lower volume of data where you don't need to perform any analytics.
I hope this helps.
Many Thanks